# How to I check a text consist of ascii code in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ascii

I want to select only the text which consist of ascii code values.

e.g

```
"Grey's Anatomy : Station 19"
"Trésors sous les mers"
"Les Légendes des Studios Marvel"
"The Great North"
"Solar Opposites"
```

I want to select it from above titles.

```
"Grey's Anatomy : Station 19"
"The Great North"
"Solar Opposites"
```

How to I filter out by postgreSQL?

Comment: What is a "ascii code value"? You mean 7-bit ASCII characters?

Comment: Do you want to allow control characters (part of ASCII: 0-31) as well?

Answer (score 4):

You could use regex matching.

```
select * from titles where title ~ '^[[:ascii:]]+$';
```

Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2402a1/8

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html